# Is there any way to not compile folders, that comes from path:{...}

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want tsc to compile my project as:

```
built/
 - package.json
 - app.js
 - etc.
```

not:

```
built/
     - test/lambda/first/src/
        - app.js
     - package.json
```

my tsconfig looks like this currently:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "declaration":true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./built",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@utils/*": ["../../../common/layers/test2/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And what i want to do is tell tsc to dont compile the folder "common" inside my built folder and also dont make a file structure like this? Is it possible with only tsconfig settings? I know how to do it with linux commands, but the point would be that tsc should handle it.

(I only want to use paths for developing, i dont actually want them in my built folder because it will access those files in the cloud)

Comment: Maybe use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [babel](https://babeljs.io/)?

Comment: You need a bundler for this. `esbuild` `snowpack` `webpack` `parcel` `babel` etc. The TypeScript Compiler only handles typescript files.

Comment: Exclude didnt work for it sadly

Comment: The point would be not to use anything other than tsc

Comment: Well, TypeScripts only job is to handle typescript-files. Not `.ico, .png, .ico, .css, .scss, .json` etc. which you likely have in your project.

Comment: It only uses typescript files, nothing else, the folder common/layers/test2 is just another nodejs project which stores all the commonly used utils and packages

Comment: well, i dont think its possible.  You can specify multiple rootDirs if i'm not mistaken. try that.